# How to filter nodes by the number of taxonomy term tagged with using exposed view filter

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a node view and the nodes listed are tagged with some terms of Vocabulary A,B,C.
And I need an exposed filter that filters the nodes by the total number of the terms of Vocabulary A and B. I can't find filter like `Taxonomy: Term - delta`
How can I do this?